Setting ControlTemplate Properties from parent container
Given this SVG converted to XAML:
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="EditSvg">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="15"
                Height="14">
            <Path Data="M3.483 3.55889H2.7183C2.31268 3.55889 1.92367 3.72003 1.63685 4.00685C1.35004 4.29366 1.1889 4.68267 1.1889 5.0883V11.9706C1.1889 12.3762 1.35004 12.7652 1.63685 13.052C1.92367 13.3389 2.31268 13.5 2.7183 13.5H9.60061C10.0062 13.5 10.3952 13.3389 10.6821 13.052C10.9689 12.7652 11.13 12.3762 11.13 11.9706V11.2059M10.3653 2.02949L12.6594 4.3236M13.7185 3.24153C14.0197 2.94036 14.1889 2.53188 14.1889 2.10595C14.1889 1.68003 14.0197 1.27155 13.7185 0.970373C13.4173 0.669198 13.0089 0.5 12.5829 0.5C12.157 0.5 11.7485 0.669198 11.4474 0.970373L5.01241 7.38239V9.67649H7.30651L13.7185 3.24153Z"
                  Fill="#00000000"
                  Stroke="white"
                  StrokeEndLineCap="round"
                  StrokeLineJoin="round"
                  StrokeStartLineCap="round" />
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ControlTemplate>

and this UI XAML code:
<Button 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Width="18" 
    Height="18"  
    Margin="0,0,5,0"
    Template="{StaticResource EditSvg}">
            
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
         <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource EditSvg}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</Button>

How would i be able to dynamically bind a brush to the Stroke Property?
I was able to do something like this:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DeleteSvg">
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="14"
                Height="16">
            <Path Data="M1.1889 4.2485H13.1889M5.6889 7.24971V11.7515M8.6889 7.24971V11.7515M1.9389 4.2485L2.6889 13.2521C2.6889 13.6501 2.84694 14.0318 3.12824 14.3132C3.40955 14.5946 3.79108 14.7527 4.1889 14.7527H10.1889C10.5867 14.7527 10.9683 14.5946 11.2496 14.3132C11.5309 14.0318 11.6889 13.6501 11.6889 13.2521L12.4389 4.2485M4.9389 4.2485V1.99759C4.9389 1.79859 5.01792 1.60775 5.15857 1.46704C5.29923 1.32633 5.48999 1.24728 5.6889 1.24728H8.6889C8.88782 1.24728 9.07858 1.32633 9.21923 1.46704C9.35989 1.60775 9.4389 1.79859 9.4389 1.99759V4.2485"
                  Fill="#00000000"
                  Stroke="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}"
                  StrokeEndLineCap="round"
                  StrokeLineJoin="round"
                  StrokeStartLineCap="round" />
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ControlTemplate>

and set the Tag on my parent control. It feels off and hacky, despite working. Is there a better way?

As the image is a part of Button, one option is to bind to Button.Foreground (Control.Foreground) property.

As @emoacht stated that would be a really nice and consistent binding, otherwise use converter or an attached property.

Okay, here is another idea: With the same binding to RelativeSource, instead of AncestorType=Control, you could use different AncestorType. It can be some class you develop in your solution as a class derived from whatever you currently use as a parent container. Don't you think it could be less hacky and more maintainable?

Unfortunately, I can't say. I'm too new to WPF to have strong feelings one way or the other.
